# MATLAB function to replace randi to generate a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, matrix, random

I have a matlab problem to solve. In have two vectores that limit my space, x_low and x_high. The matrix pos needs to have values within this spaces and each column of the matrix has different bounds given by the two vectores. Now my problem is that randi gives valus between two integers but i need to change the bounds for each columns. There is another way to use randi or a different matlab function to do this?
I know  there are better codes to do this but i'm starting to use matlab and i know to do it this way, any aid is welcome

```
x_low = [Io_low, Iirr_low, Rp_low, Rs_low, n_low];   % vector of constant values
x_high = [Io_high, Iirr_high, Rp_high, Rs_high, n_high];    % vector of constant values 
pos = rand(particles, var);
var = length(x_high);
for i = 1: particles        % rows                                                   
  for k = 1: var         %columns                                    
    if pos(i, k) < x_low(k) || pos(i, k) > x_high(k)    % if the position is out of bounder     
        pos(i, k) = randi(x_low(k), x_high(k), 1);    % fill it with a particle whithin the bounderies     
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to **generate a matrix with integer values such that each column has different lower and upper limits**; and those lower and upper limits are inclusive.

This can be done very simply with

- [`rand`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) (to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 ),
- [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (to take care of the lower and upper limits on a column basis), and
- [`round`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) (so that the results are integer values).

Let the input data be defined as

```
x_low =  [1  6  11];  %// lower limits
x_high = [3 10 100];  %// upper limits
n_rows = 7;           %// number of columns
```

Then:

```
r = rand(n_rows, numel(x_low));                %// random numbers between 0 and 1
r = floor(bsxfun(@times, r, x_high-x_low+1));  %// adjust span and round to integers
r = bsxfun(@plus, r, x_low);                   %// adjust lower limit
```

gives something like

```
r =
     2     7    83
     3     6    93
     2     6    22
     3    10    85
     3     7    96
     1    10    90
     2     8    57
```

---

If you need to fill in values only at specific entries of matrix `pos`, you can use something like

```
ind = bsxfun(@lt, pos, x_low) | bsxfun(@gt, pos, x_high); %// index of values to replace
pos(ind) = r(ind);
```

This a little overkill, because the whole matrixd `r` is generated only to use some of its entries. To generate only the needed values the best way is probably to use loops.

Comment: @Andy I'm glad to hear that. `bsxfun` is a very powerful function. The fact that you find this more readable than `cellfun` says a lot about your Matlab skills :-)

Comment: On the contrary! (I wasn't trying to be ironic at all) Getting used to `bsxfun` is one of the best ways to writing  good, elegant, performant Matlab code.

Comment: sorry the other question but i would know if it is possible just to change the particles there are outside the limits, i mean i i have some particles within my different limits,i don' t need to change them, while if they are out of bound i need to change. With your algorithm i change the whole matrix pos while i just need to change the particles that don' t respect my limits, that was the reason of two for loops, to control each point of the matrix. Is that possible?

Comment: @Andy I hand't understood your question correctly. Please see edit. However, using loops may be faster, as I'm generating the whole matrix to only use some of its entries

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cellfun` for this. Something like:

```
x_low = [Io_low, Iirr_low, Rp_low, Rs_low, n_low];
x_high = [Io_high, Iirr_high, Rp_high, Rs_high, n_high];

pos = cell2mat(cellfun(@randi, mat2cell([x_low' x_high'], ones(numel(x_low),1), 1), repmat({[particles 1]}, [numel(x_low) 1)])))';
```

Best,

Comment: Thank you but i chose the second answer that is more readable to me.